# C# Function works on development machine but fails on web

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have this function in my Visual Studio web app and it seems to work just fine when I run the project on the development machine, but when I publish it to the web and go to the page where the function runs, it always runs the catch exception part. Can anyone help? I'm scratching my head here :( Here is the code for the function.

```
public void printData()
{
    try
    {
        //The path to the Bid Form
        string pdfPath = Server.MapPath("PDF/Bid_Form.pdf");
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        var pdfOutput = new MemoryStream();
        var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfOutput);
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        //This code block gets the date
        string date = BidDateTextBox.Value;
        DateTime dateNow = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        string newDate = dateNow.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy", ci);

        //This gets the values from the hidden fields
        decimal airTotal = (Convert.ToDecimal(at.Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(att.Value));
        decimal waterTotal = (Convert.ToDecimal(wt.Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(wtt.Value));
        decimal preTestAir = String.IsNullOrEmpty(AirPreTestTextBox.Value) ? 0 : decimal.Parse(AirPreTestTextBox.Value);
        decimal preTestWater = String.IsNullOrEmpty(WaterPreTestTextBox.Value) ? 0 : decimal.Parse(WaterPreTestTextBox.Value);
        decimal preTestCombine = preTestAir + preTestWater;
        decimal airTotalAll = (Convert.ToDecimal(at.Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(att.Value) + preTestAir);
        decimal waterTotalAll = (Convert.ToDecimal(wt.Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(wtt.Value) + preTestWater);

        //This line gets the total of all areas
        decimal combineTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(gt.Value);

        //This line gets the checked check boxes in the Per Specifications area
        string selectedSpecItems = (String.Join(",", CheckBoxList1.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(r => r.Selected).Select(r => r.Text)) + ", " + CustomSpecTextBox.Value);

        //This line gets the checked check boxes in the Exclusions area
        string selectedExItems = (String.Join(",", CheckBoxList2.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(r => r.Selected).Select(r => r.Text)) + ", " + CustomExcTextBox.Value);

        //This checks if the pre test check box is checked. If so it doesnt include the pretest amounts.
        if (PreTestCheckBox.Checked) {
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("PreTestAirBid", "$" + preTestAir);
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("PreTestWaterBid", "$" + preTestWater);
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("PreTestCombineBid", "$" + preTestCombine);
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("PreTestText", "Pre-Test");
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("AirBid", "$" + airTotal);
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("WaterBid", "$" + waterTotal);
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("CombineBid", "$" + combineTotal);
        }
        else
        {
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("PreTestAirBid", "");
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("PreTestWaterBid", "");
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("PreTestCombineBid", "");
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("AirBid", "$" + airTotalAll);
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("WaterBid", "$" + waterTotalAll);
            pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("CombineBid", "$" + combineTotal);

        }
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Date", "" + newDate);
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Bid#", "");
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Location", "" + LocationTextBox.Value);
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("ProjectName", "" + ProjectNameTextBox.Value);
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Engineer", "" + EngineerTextBox.Value);
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("EngineerPhone", "");
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("EngineerFax", "");
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Architect", "" + ArchitectTextBox.Value);
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("ArchitectPhone", "");
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("ArchitectFax", "");
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Specifications", "" + selectedSpecItems);
        pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("Exclusions", "" + selectedExItems);
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfReader.Close();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=NewBid.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdfOutput.ToArray());
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", "alert('An error has occured.');", true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to change `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", "alert('An error has occured.');", true);` to `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", "alert('" + e.Message + "');", true);`, then tell us what the error message is.

Comment: It would be easier if you can get some information about the error being triggered. I recommend you to add some logging mechanism as log4net.

Comment: "fails" how? You're catching the exception but never looking at its details. Does the account running your AppPool have permissions to write a file in that location?

Comment: @ekad Ok I will do that and let you know what the error is. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're catching the exception for catching an exceptions sake and just disregarding it... do something with the exception's message and/or stack trace as a starting point - even if it's just throwing it on your screen or backing out to the YSOD.

Comment: Looks like it is trying to find a PDF file that isn't in the correct directory. Thanks for the help everyone. @ekad your code sample helped out a bunch thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exception my guess would be the server does not have appropriate access to the file at the path you are referencing. Try outputting the exception message in the catch block instead of your custom error message. Should help.